# CSV Helper export csv and encoding

Tags: .net-core, encoding, export-to-csv, c#-3.0, csvhelper

iam trying to export  csv file   using  csvhelper  and dotnet core  but when the data have french letters as  chéri it is converted to chï¿½ri , i checked  couple of answers but nothing work 
...

```
       using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, 
                     System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csvWriter.Configuration.ReferenceHeaderPrefix = (membertype, memberName) => $"{memberName}";

                   csvWriter.Configuration.AutoMap<T>();


                csvWriter.WriteRecords(items);
            }

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

...

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with the given example and `CsvHelper` v 15.0, on random class I'm getting correct `0xE9` byte for the `é` iso-8859-1 letter. How `items`/`T` is defined? And how the output of `return memoryStream.ToArray()` is processed further?

Comment: CsvHelper v 15.0 is version 15 , items is the list of item we sent to export ,  the `return var csvFileBytes =this.csvConverter.GetCSVFile(items,typeof(CaseFileDenormalizedMap));
 return csvFileBytes != null ? this.File(csvFileBytes, "text/csv", "export.csv")` , the error happen when you open it using excel